# Can we solve the ODE system with Green Function Methods?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, greens-function

Can we solve the following ODE system by Green Functions Method? Could you give some hints?

$\ddot{x}_1(t)+a_1x_1(t)-a_2x_2(t)=f_1(t)$,

$\ddot{x}_2(t)+a_3x_2(t)-a_4x_1(t)=f_2(t)$,

where $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ are constants.

The given conditions are as follows: ${x}_1(0)=k,{x}_2(0)=l,\dot{x}_1(0)=m,\dot{x}_2(0)=n$ where $k, l, m, n$ are constants.
($f_1(t),f_2(t)$ are ungiven functions.)

(You can find the transformed first order differential eq's. system of the second order system)

Comment: I would write the second order system as a first order system, then use first order Green's function methods. In either case, finding the Green's function is the main problem, as you can simply integrate to get the solution.

Comment: If we define $z_1=x_1,z_2=\dot{x}_1, z_3=x_2,z_4=\dot{x}_3$, we get the following first order ode system:
$$\dot{z}_1(t)=z_2(t)$$
$$\dot{z}_2(t)=-a_1z_1(t)+a_2z_3(t)+f_1(t)$$
$$\dot{z}_3(t)=z_4(t)$$
$$\dot{z}_4(t)=-a_3z_3(t)+a_4z_1(t)+f_2(t)$$
could you help the rest ?